# lisp proprieties of entity not updating after entmod?

Tags: lisp, autocad

I'm kinda a noob at lisp and i'm doing a little project that aims to change the height of a text, color, and also put the text inside a rectangle, but everytime i call the txtedit function, the text changes correctly but the rectangle is forming around the initial size of  the text, seeming to be a problem with the x axis, but on the second try on the modified text, it works ok if I input the same height , any tips because i'm kinda stuck?
[how it looks after i call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZYF2.jpg)////////
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq6Fs.jpg)

Comment: We, programmers, are too lazy to rewrite the code You write once. 

Maybe You will find someone who helps You in this way, but it will be easier if you copy and paste the code for us to test and debug.

Comment: Please visit this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It will help each of us.